# Overlay an image segmentation with numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to overlay two images. The first one is a 512x512 NumPy array (from a CT image). The second one is also a 512x512 NumPy array but I am just interested in the pixels where the value is larger than 0 (a functional image).

To do that I am trying to create a masked array.

```
import numpy as np 
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Both images are loaded from a dicom. Both are numpy arrays of (512,512) 
Image1 = readimage(path)
Image2 = readimage(path)
# Create image 2 mask
mask = ma.masked_where(Image2>0, Image2)
Image2_mask = ma.masked_array(Image2,mask)

# Plot images
plt.figure(dpi=300)
y, x = np.mgrid[1:513,1:513]
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.set_cmap(plt.gray())
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, Image1,cmap='gray')
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, Image2_mask,cmap='jet')
plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This code does not show any overlay. What I am doing wrong? Is there any straight way? I am coming from a Matlab environment and I am quite new to Python.

Comment: Could you please provide the start of this code too?
`e.g. ma = ...`

Comment: I eddited the post to include the first part of the code. Both images are loaded from a function which extracts from a CT dicom, I belive this is not important. The image type is:
`Image.dtype
Out[33]: dtype('int16')`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Why don't you use `imshow` instead?

You can plot a 2D image by doing:

```
plt.imshow(Image1, cmap='gray') # I would add interpolation='none'
```

Afterwards, you can easily overlay the segmentation by doing:

```
plt.imshow(Image2_mask, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5) # interpolation='none'
```

Changing the alpha will change the opacity of the overlay.

Additionaly, why do you create 2 masks? Only one should be enough, you can do:

```
Image2_mask = ma.masked_array(Image2 > 0, Image2)
```

---

Practical example:

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.zeros((10,10))
mask[3:-3, 3:-3] = 1 # white square in black background
im = mask + np.random.randn(10,10) * 0.01 # random image
masked = np.ma.masked_where(mask == 0, mask)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(im, 'gray', interpolation='none')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(im, 'gray', interpolation='none')
plt.imshow(masked, 'jet', interpolation='none', alpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Completing the Imanol Luengo's answer : masking image could be directly handled in imshow alpha option by putting an alpla image ie.

```
plt.imshow(Image1, cmap='gray') # I would add interpolation='none'
plt.imshow(Image2, cmap='jet', alpha=0.5*(Image2>0)   ) # interpolation='none'
```

Answer (score 6):

I can give you my function to overlap a picture and a mask of dataset :

```
def get_overlapped_img(filename, img_folder, mask_folder):
    # Import orginal img
    img = cv2.imread(img_folder+"/"+filename+".jpg")

    # Import and convert the mask from binary to RGB
    mask = Image.open(mask_folder+"/"+filename+".png").convert('RGB')
width, height = mask.size

    # Convert the white color (for blobs) to magenta
    mask_colored = change_color(mask, width, height, (255, 255, 255), (186,85,211))
    # Convert the black (for background) to white --> important to make a good overlapping
    mask_colored = change_color(mask_colored, width, height, (0, 0, 0), (255,255,255))

    return cv2.addWeighted(np.array(img),0.4,np.array(mask_colored),0.3,0)
```

Function to change color of each pixel in a picture :

```
def change_color(picture, width, height, ex_color, new_color):
    # Process every pixel
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
            if current_color == ex_color:
                picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
    return picture
```

Answer (score 5):

Though not directly with matplotlib, one alternative could be to use [nilearn](https://nilearn.github.io/stable/index.html) which is built on top of matplotlib. If working with nifti files (typical extension in neuroimaging), you can use the functions `plot_roi` or `add_overlay`.

For instance, as suggested in [this thread](https://neurostars.org/t/how-to-overlay-a-mask-image-on-another-mri-image-using-nilearn-plotting/5185/3?u=tommaso_di_noto), you could write:

```
>>> from nilearn import plotting
>>> display = plotting.plot_anat('path/to/volume.nii.gz')  # plot volume 
>>> display.add_overlay('path/to/mask.nii.gz',cmap='hot', colorbar=True)  # add mask
```

If you are only interested in certain planes/views, you can play with the arguments `display_mode` and `cut_coords`

The final results would be something like:
[image]