# Matplotlib / Imshow / transparent layer everywhere but certain points

Tags: python, matplotlib, layer, imshow

I try to plot a layer on an imshow. This layer is based on a matrix where every values are equals to 0 but some specific pixels are equals to 1.

If I use the alpha parameter, I'm loosing mycolor as well... How can I have 0% transparency where I have a "1" value in my layer and 100% transparency where it is equals to 0 ?

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,5,6)
y = x

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = (X**2+Y-11)**2

plt.imshow(Z,cmap='jet')

layer = np.zeros((6,6))
layer[3,3] = 1
layer[2,4] = 1
plt.imshow(layer,alpha=0.1,cmap = 'Purples')
```

thx for your help!

**Edit: How I tried to give an alpha matrix**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,5,6)
y = x

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = (X**2+Y-11)**2

plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(Z,cmap='jet')

layer = np.zeros((6,6))
layer[3,3] = 1
layer[2,4] = 1

alphas = layer.copy()

alphas[alphas==0]=0.1
alphas[alphas==1]=0.9


plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(layer,alpha=0.9,cmap = 'Reds')

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.imshow(Z,cmap='jet')
plt.imshow(layer,alpha=alphas,cmap = 'Reds')
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with masks. If I understand well, the "mask" is applied on the data, not on the picture. right ? If yes, prefer not to modify my initial picture and continue to use my "layer".  I was thinking to use for example a matrix of alphas to define the transparency square by square. But it seems it is not working (or I'm doing it wrong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the idea of masking as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31878180/4932316). Here, `masked_where` will return a `MaskedArray` which will be masked if `layer=0` and 1 if `layer=1`. This way, you will get a 100% transparency where `layer` is equals to 0 and 0% transparency where layer is "1"

```
ax = plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(Z,cmap='jet')

layer = np.zeros((6,6))
layer[3,3] = 1
layer[2,4] = 1

masked = np.ma.masked_where(layer == 0, layer)
ax.imshow(masked,alpha=1,cmap = 'Reds')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Okkk, I was ignoring this function. I manually tried with a NaN, but is was not working. Thant you, great help!